# Determine extension state

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I would like to make any changes in user preferences in-memory while the extension is running, and only save the preferences (as a JSON obj) to localStorage when the extension is about to terminate (I use a background html page in my extension).

I am currently writing to localStorage every time a preference is changed but am looking to see if this can be made more efficient to avoid writing to disk on each preference change and instead just do it once before termination.

Is there any way to know when the extension is being terminated or does anyone know of a better approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: This is not possible. The [`management` API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html#global-events) provides events for uninstallation of extensions. However, when an extension is disabled, the code inside the event listener is not triggered any more, since the extension's lifetime has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
 function saveSettings(){
     window.clearTimeout(window.savingSettings);
     return window.savingSettings = window.setTimeout(function(){ 
         ... // write to local storage here.
     },2000)
 };
```

This will makes sure:

1. there's at least two seconds between save operations
2. the whole thing runs somewhat parallelized to the main thread

You should see a performance boost to some degree but there's a catch. If a user closes the browser without waiting those two seconds after changing a pref, prefs won't be saved.